# Приведение числа double к float с большой точностью

Tags: c++, float, double

Пусть у меня есть некоторое значение типа double, мне необходимо провести некоторые манипуляции над этим значением и конвертировать в тип float.
Имею такие данные:

```
double x = 12058660.309519000;
float xx = x * 0.1f;
```

когда я проверяю через отладку выражение для переменной `xx` получаю - **1205866.0309518999**, но когда проверяю само значение переменной `xx`, то получаю - **1205866.00**

Почему?

Мне необходимо сохранить точность.

Comment: Хотите сохранить точность - сделайте xx тоже double. А float по определению обеспечивает меньшую точность, чем double.

Comment: @Voidificator, мне необходим именно тип float для переменной xx.

Comment: Максимальную точность обеспечит формат с фиксированной точкой: переход от `float/double` к дробям. Комментарий про `Decimal` в C# верный. Посмотрите, как то же самое реализуется в нативных `c/c++`: [Альтернатива с фиксированной точностью десятичной дроби](https://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/257897/). Этот формат гибче управляет точностью, чем `float/double`.

Comment: В дополнение к ответам, добавлю, что результат выражения `x * 0.1f` имеет тип `double`. Это обусловлено тем, что переменная `x` имеет тип `double`, а значит и литерал `0.1f` за счёт механизма обычных арифметических преобразований (_usual arithmetic conversions_) также будет приведён к типу `double`. И уже потом, в процессе присвоения, значение типа `double` усекается до `float`. Еще один занятный момент состоит в том, что `0.1f` **не** равно `0.1` [Пруф](https://ideone.com/0WBGQl).

Answer (score 3):

Вы уперлись в точность. Точность `float` — 7-8 знаков. Это значит, что `float` может хранить только 7 или 8(нечет и чет соответственно) цифр. Возьмите число с целой частью поменьше(1234, допустим), и у вас останется еще `8-4==4` цифры для дробной части.

Точность `double`(число двойной точности) - 15 знаков. Как можете заметить, `double` у вас тоже округляется до 15-го знака, причем не после запятой, а вообще. Округление связано с тем, что в памяти компьютера все числа представляются в двоичной системе счисления. Поэтому дробные числа в большинстве своем представляются в виде дроби, а уже она потом округляется, что вы и видите.

В `float` вы не сможете хранить больше 7-8 цифр, повторяю еще раз.

Comment: В C# что-то такое тоже есть, сейчас проверю, как именно называется. И в С++ тоже

Comment: Что ж, в C# есть Decimal, а для С++ придется использовать библиотеку типа gmp: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: нет конкретного ответа на конкретный вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Проведем простой эксперимент

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  float f = 1205866;
  printf("%.10f\n", f);
  printf("%.10f .. %.10f\n", nextafterf(f, 0), nextafterf(f, 1e8f));
}
```

Получаем

```
1205866.0000000000
1205865.8750000000 .. 1205866.1250000000
```

Это - ближайшие соседние числа, представимые в IEEE 754 типе `float`. Никакие другие значения в этой окрестности тип `float` представить не может.

То есть ни о каком `1205866.0309518999` не может быть и речи. `1205866` - это *ближайшее* к вашему `1205866.0309518999` представимое значение типа `float`. Вот и ответ на ваш вопрос "Почему?".

Таким образом вы прекрасно "сохранили точность" - настолько, насколько это вообще возможно в выбранном вами типе. Если вы хотите еще лучше "сохранить точность", то тип `float` вам тут помочь не сможет. Используйте более точные типы. А если вам абсолютно необходимо конвертировать результат в тип `float`, то - увы...

Например, аналогичный эксперимент с типом `double` даст нам

```
1205866.00000000000000000000
1205865.99999999976716935635 .. 1205866.00000000023283064365
```

Как видите, "шаг" типа `double` в этой окрестности несравнимо мельче, чем ваше `.0309...`.